# How to know when a trigger was disabled/enabled?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

There is a trigger that was disabled on the database. Is there a way I can know from a oracle (maybe metadata/data dictionary table ) when it was disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT OWNER, TRIGGER_NAME, STATUS
FROM ALL_TRIGGERS
WHERE STATUS = 'DISABLED';
```

You can also use

```
SELECT t.OWNER, TRIGGER_NAME, t.STATUS, LAST_DDL_TIME
FROM ALL_OBJECTS obj
    JOIN ALL_TRIGGERS t ON t.owner = obj.owner AND TRIGGER_NAME = OBJECT_NAME;
```

`LAST_DDL_TIME` shows the last DDL which might be when the trigger was disabled. However, it can be anything else what has been modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through Oracle AUDIT, if you've enabled auditing for ALTER TRIGGER or ALTER TABLE (it's not on by default).

Otherwise you might be able to infer it from USER_OBJECTS.LAST_DDL_TIME for the trigger, but obviously that time is set by other DDL besides enabling or disabling.

Answer (score 1):

Use the query below:

`SELECT
    object_name,
    last_ddl_time
FROM
    dba_objects
WHERE
    object_name IN (
        SELECT
            object_name
        FROM
            dba_triggers
        WHERE
            status = 'DISABLED'
    )
ORDER BY
    1;`